# Infinite loop in MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips

I am attempting to write a program for a class in the MIPS assembly language that will read a series of integers from a word and print out the highest and lowest values. So far I have just been trying to get it to print out the highest value. I have modified some provided code from the course and stepped through it with qt SPIM. I believe my conditional statement is never evaluated. I think that I fail to load the next word and my comparisons never cause the program to increment. I've tried troubleshooting quite a bit and am stuck. below is the full code. I will comment out where I feel the error is. I can tell from QT that my loop is infinite.

```
.text

main:   
        la      $a0, TABLE      # Load a value for argument
        la      $a1, n          # Load the second argument
        jal     high_low    # jump to high_low subroutine

        move    $a0, $v0      # Load the return of subroutine into argument
        li      $v0, 1          # print out the result from the subroutine
        syscall

        b       exit

### high_low subroutine ###
### returns the sum of the highest and lowest integer:
        subu    $sp, $sp, 8     # Setup a stack frame by allocating space
        sw      $ra, 4($sp)     # Store the return address
        sw      $fp, ($sp)      # Store the old frame pointer
        addu    $fp, $sp, 8     # Reset the frame pointer to the bottom of current           frame

        move    $t0, $a0        # Load first argument into $t0
        move    $t1, $a1        # Load second argument into $t1
        li      $t2, 0          # Initialize the value of $t2, this will be the counter

 high_low_loop:
        bgt     $t2, $t1, counting_sum_end # If the first number is larger, the loop ends
        # is this how i would get to the next integer in table? I feel this is where
        # i am incorrect and thus my conditional is never evaluated. 
        addu    $t3, $t0, 4     # move next digit to be read
        bgt     $t0, $t3, G1    # if t0 is great increment
G1:      
        addi    $t2, $t2, 1     # Increment $t0

        bgt     $t3, $t0, G2    # if t3 is bigger move it to t1 & increment
G2:         
        move    $t3, $t0        # move to t0, if t3 is larger  
        addi    $t2, $t2, 1     # increment counter

        addi    $t2, $t2, 1     # increment counter
        b high_low_loop     #  and repeat the loop

counting_sum_end:
        move    $v0, $t0        # Load highest into $v0 for return
        lw      $fp, ($sp)      # Unpack the stack frame
        lw      $ra, 4($sp)     # load the return address into $ra
        addu    $sp, $sp, 8     # restore stack pointer

        jr      $ra



exit:           li $v0, 10 # load exit instruction
            syscall    # and end program

.data
#TABLE:    .word   3  -1  6  5  7  -3  -15  18  2 
#n:        .word   9
TABLE:  .word   3
n:      .word   1
# end of add.asm
```

Where you see G1 and G2, i felt I had to put in something to send it back to the start of the loop. ex: b high_low_loop , but i received a syntax error. Any direction would be great as I am very new to mips.

Comment: Why does `TABLE` only have 1 element?

Comment: I was just testing it to see if I could get the loop to move through even once. Since posting this I have learned a lot more about exactly how this should go. Perhaps I'll update the post shortly with how things look now in case someone else may find it useful